# How to check the security of the SSL certificate in iOS?

Tags: ios, security, ios5, ios4, ssl-certificate

I wanna check whether the SSL certificate is present in the URL also wants to check its version and validation type.

I have created a application where I am calling the NSURLConnection delegate methods to send request over a server.

Also used **"canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace"** method, but this method is not getting called once the connection is established.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

iOS does not give you very granular access to certificate information. You have two choices: private APIs or build your own evaluator with OpenSSL.

You can see the private certificate functions in the [opensource code](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/libsecurity_keychain/libsecurity_keychain-55044/lib/SecCertificatePrivP.h). The version is available from `SecCertificateVersion()`. I'm not certain what you mean by "validation type" here.

To do this with OpenSSL, you can get the DER data with `SecCertificateCopyData()` and then parse everything yourself.

I suggest opening a radar (bugreporter.apple.com) on this issue. The lack of access to basic information about the certificate is a serious problem.

If you're looking for sample code that extracts the certificate from the `NSURLConnection`, see the [Chapter 11 sample code](https://github.com/rnapier/ios5ptl/blob/master/ch11/Connection/Connection/ConnectionViewController.m) from [iOS:PTL](http://iosptl.com):

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
  willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:
  (NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{
  NSURLProtectionSpace *protSpace = challenge.protectionSpace;
  SecTrustRef trust = protSpace.serverTrust;
  ...
    SecCertificateRef cert = SecTrustGetCertificateAtIndex(trust, 0);
  ...
```

At this point, `cert` holds your leaf certificate.

Comment: Thanks for your suggesion."validation type" means what validation type of SSL is implemented on the URL, either Standard or Extended Validation. Here I have used the code given in "Chapter 11 sample code" but when I am trying to build the app I am getting compile time errors a --> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_SecPolicyCreateBasicX509", referenced from:
      _RNSecTrustEvaluateAsX509 in ConnectionViewController.o, "_SecCertificateNotValidAfter", referenced from:
      -[ConnectionViewController connection:willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:] in ConnectionViewController.o