# Javascript SSL version

Tags: javascript, cordova, ssl

does anyone know where to find which TSL (SSL) version is used when sending an HTTPS request?

Currently I need to find out if and which TSL version is used when sending such a request from PhoneGap.

My best quess would be that this is based on the browser and it's version.
As this is usually the native browser inside PhoneGap I am looking for a list of the browsers.

Found [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19096/how-to-determine-if-a-browser-is-using-an-ssl-or-tls-connection), but it does not help me on native browsers.
Any idea?

Best Kurt

Answer (score 0):

You should implement your own plugin using native code:

Android: [How to find what SSL/TLS version is used in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10500511/how-to-find-what-ssl-tls-version-is-used-in-java)

IOS: [How to check the security of the SSL certificate in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412643/how-to-check-the-security-of-the-ssl-certificate-in-ios)

Comment: This is very close to link-only answers. Can you expand a bit (preferably offering some code)? Otherwise, the system might delete this answer.

Comment: In my opinion there is no JS way to solve the problem.